# Inequality for $s\in(1,2)$ and $p\geq 2$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, inequality, integral-inequality

Let $s\in(1,2)$ and $p\geq 2$, then there exists a constant $c(p)$ large depending on $p$ such that
$$
s^p-1-(s-1)^p\leq c(p)(s-1).
$$
For $p=2,3$ I have verified it but for other values of $p$, I am unable to verify it. Can somebody kindly help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you familiar with [MVT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem)? If yes, then think about $$s^p-1-(s-1)^p=f(s)-f(1)$$
where
$$f(x)=x^p-1-(x-1)^p$$

Comment: Yes, but unable to apply it. Can you please help. Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by "unable to apply"? You need to show that $f(x)$ is continuous on $[1,2]$ and differentiable on $(1,2)$. Then calculate the derivative and see if you can bound it on $[1,2]$.

Comment: Yes, I think this is the argument. Let $s\in(1,2)$. Then by MVT, $f(s)-f(1)=(s-1)f'(c)$ for some $c\in(1,2)$. Since $c\in(1,s)$ and $s<2$, we get $|f'(c)|\leq M$ for some constant $M$. Therefore, we get $f(s)-f(1)\leq M(s-1)$ for a fixed $s\in(1,2). But we need for every $s\in (1,2)$ and $c(p)$ independent of $s$. Can you kindly explain. Thanks.

Comment: Did you calculate $f'(x)$?

Comment: Once you calculate it, you'll see that $f'(x)\leq p2^{p-1}=c(p),\forall x\in(1,2)$.

Comment: Yes, Thank you very much. I appreciate very much your answer.